# Broke Plesk During Delete Operation

Tags: plesk

My server ran out of diskspace and I ran the following command in SSH:

```
sudo find / -type f -size +10000k | xargs rm -Rf
```

I had intended to hone my folder scope to my mail directory, but alas hit enter without doing so.

I'm pretty confident I must have deleted something important in Plesk because it now throws a 500 Internal Server Error. I checked out the error logs and it is repeatedly throwing this:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.3811) pid  8181 5 not found: No child processes
```

My host (Media Temple) offers the ability to save a snapshot of the server and reset it do default, but I'd really like to avoid this if possible. My production website + database is all A-Okay. Plesk is the only thing that I can see that is throwing errors.

Is there any other solution to this problem? I was thinking about just reinstalling Plesk, but I'm not sure what the effect of this would be on my email accounts and mysql database.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the safest path would be to order new Plesk server from MediaTemple, use Plesk MIgration & Transfer tool to move your site to a new server and abandon original server then. This way your original server won't be affected until you have new one setup and validated.

I am afraid you have killed Plesk managing database...